# Dismissing View Controller for osx

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I'm trying to learn swift code for mac OSX but there isn't much tutorials for it as ios. and i have been struggling already with closing or dismissing the view controller when i launch through a button another connected view controller

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var username: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: NSTextField!
@IBAction func login(sender: AnyObject) {
}


@IBAction func signUp(sender: AnyObject) {


}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}
```

}

I tried to add [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; to dismiss it but it doesn't work it only shows errors. if anybody could point me to somewhere i can get more information or what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: If this is about OS X, why do you have an "ios" tag?

Comment: as far as my research went. osx and ios dev is almost the same. so i put it up maybe someone with ios background can help? no ?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
dismissViewController(self)
```

to dismiss the presented view controller.

---

About `dismissViewController:` from the `NSViewController` docs:

> Dismisses a presented view controller, using the same animator that presented it.

and

> In OS X, this is the universal way to dismiss a view controller, no matter how it was presented.

Comment: sorry Daniel. but when i put on view did load i get an error

Comment: Put it in a button action or something on the presented view controller. I don't think you want to dismiss the view controller right after it loads.

Comment: When i put it in sign up. and then press it. it still stays there

Comment: Maybe your view controller was not presented? For example, a view controller would be presented if it were displayed using a Modal segue.

Comment: I am using a modal segue that presents the next view controller on button click

Comment: Is the `dismissViewController(self)` called from the view controller that is presented?

Comment: I tried both daniel. from the presented and the one presenting it to close it self once button is clicked. i added it to the signUp button